# how to insert video and audio files in sql server2012 using query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

To handle media files, can somebody tell me how to insert a video and audio files into sql server 2012 using query.i'm new to sql

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest(AudioMP3 VARBINARY(MAX));

INSERT INTO #tmpTest(AudioMP3)
SELECT
(
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\PathToMusic\FileName.mp3', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
);

SELECT * FROM #tmpTest;
GO

DROP TABLE #tmpTest;
```

Comment: For audio it's working for me

Comment: how to insert a videos

Comment: @silambarasanvediappan Just the same? `SELECT ... FROM OPENROWSET(... SINGLE_BLOB)` will read any file from the given path just as a chain of bits and will place this in a `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

Comment: Great!!, videos also get working now, thanks you so much @Shnugo